# Meaning of the word どんこ

Tags: words

> 「なんて立派な干しシイタケ。上等の**どんこ**だよっ。」
>   What splendid dried mushrooms! They're first-class ????

What is どんこ in this sentence? The dictionaries only mention a kind of fish.

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B1#.E5.B9.B2.E3.81.97.E3.81.97.E3.81.84.E3.81.9F.E3.81.91 http://d.hatena.ne.jp/seikatukankyou/20091210/p2

Comment: That's way too difficult for me to read, but I see that it's a very mushroom specific word. Thanks.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/byTME.jpg

Comment: ^ That's a fish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the text says ”立派な干ししいたけ,” it's not a fish called "どんこ,” famously found in the Ariake shoal in northern Kyushu.

どんこ（冬子、冬菇  in Kanji）is a shiitake mushroom grown in winter time. It has a thick “body and meat,” and is very delicious. The dried “Donko” is regarded as the highest class of shiitake and precious. It could be our 垂涎の的 ー the target of gourmands.

Comment: I can confirm this with a Super Daijirin Japanese Dictionary.

Comment: 冬菇 *dōnggū* is also the Chinese word for the shiitake.